# Obtener cadena Json desde $_POST en Yii2

Tags: json, array, post, yii2

trato de hacer una consulta con $.post de JQuery haciendo lo siguiente:

```js
function consultaAjax(url, val){
    arreglo = { id: val };
    datos = JSON.stringify(arreglo);
    $.post( 
            url, 
            datos, 
            function(data){$("select#documentos-expedicion").html( data );}
    );}
```

y en el controlador tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public function actionGetinfo(){

    $json = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $data = json_decode($json[0], true); // <- aqui esta el problema

    echo 'fuck '.$data; // esto no importa, solo me siento frustrado
}
```

$json es un arreglo unidimencional que contiene la cadena JSON, (esto lo sé gracias al depurador de Netbeans) el problema cuando trato de acceder al array es que lanza el error:

```
$data = $json[0]; // error "Undefined offset: 0"
$data = $json[1]; // error "Undefined offset: 1"
$data = $json['id']; // error "Undefined index: id"
```

si se lo paso completo al "json_decode()" me dice que esperaba una cadena json y que le he pasado un array y obvio "error".

¿como puedo acceder al arreglo?, ¿existe algún procedimiento que me esté saltando?, y de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

he resuelto el problema después de mucho trabajo.

El problema principal se presenta por que "google chrome" el navegador bajo el cual estoy desarrollando la aplicación, carga los assets de la aplicacion y no los actualiza a menos que se borre la memoria cache con herramientas como "ccleaner" o se desabilite la opcion "cache" en las opciones para desarrolladores.

1. clic derecho sobre la pagina seleccionar **inspeccionar elemento**.
2. en la ventana que se abre clic sobre los tres puntos verticales en la
   esquina superior derecha.
3. clic en **Settings**.
4. buscar el apartado **Network** y seleccionar la opcion "**Disable cache (while DevTools is
   open**)".

después de estos pasos y siempre y cuando la herramienta para desarrolladores este abierta Chrome cargara siempre los Js, Css y demás assets cuando se refresque la pagina.

ademas de esto les muestro como quedo el código final por si alguien mas lo necesita.

```js
function consultaAjax(url, val){
    datos = { id: val };
    $.post( url, 
            datos, 
            function(data){$("select#documentos-expedicion").html( data );}
    );}
```

Controlador php...

```
public function actionGetcites(){

    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');

    $cities = Municipios::find()->where(['departamento' => $id])->all();

    if($cities > 0){
        foreach($cities as $city){
            echo "<option value='".$city->id."'>".$city->nombre."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>No hay ciudades que mostrar</option>";
    }}
```